# Case of Punctured Tyre

Tags: lateral-thinking, situation

A man drove his Innova car all the way from Shimla to Delhi only to discover at the end of the trip that he had a punctured tyre from the very start. Yet his Innova car was not at all affected by it. How is this possible?

(Source: https://www.hitbullseye.com/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps

> The punctured tire was his spare tire inside the car/below the trunk?

Comment: Another possibility is that the punctured tire was on his other car.

Answer (score 11):

The man was

> transporting his Innova on the back of a truck. He "drove his car to Delhi" the same way one might "drive their friend home" - he transported the car by road, but did not actually drive the car itself. Obviously, having a flat tire on a car that's strapped to the back of a truck will make no difference for the journey.

Answer (score 8):

I think that maybe

> He punctured the spare tyre (stored in the boot of the car)

Comment: Great minds think alike! Might’ve pipped you by a couple seconds haha.

Comment: @El-Guest Yes, one second according to the timestamps

Comment: And all the Americans are wondering how he stored a besieged city in a shoe.... : )